# How to get current route in Vue 3 outside of component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

When I'm outside of Vue component, i.e. in a store, `router.currentRoute.name` is undefined:

```
import router from '@/router'
console.log(router.currentRoute.name) // returns "undefined"
```

I can't use `useRouter` composable either, because it doesn't work outside of components:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()
console.log(router) // returns "undefined"
```

This has never been a problem in Vue 2, where router was created with `new Router()`.
In Vue 3, when using router with the new `createRouter()`, the exported router doesn't seem to expose `router.currentRoute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3 instead of

```
router.currentRoute.name
```

route name should be accessed with:

```
router.currentRoute.value.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `createRouter`?

```js
import {createRouter, createWebHashHistory} from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
// your routes
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: routes
});

console.log(router);
console.log(router.currentRoute.value.path);

export default router;
```

I use this sequence in a module `router.js` that exports the router. This router then is imported in `main.js` and injected into the app (`myApp.use(router)`). It can also be imported in other modules and used there. For example, I use it tis way for unittests.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the current route is simply not initialized yet?

For example in the root app component:

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { watch } from 'vue'

const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.name) // -> undefined

watch(route, () => {
  console.log(route.name) // -> route.name is defined
})
```

In a view loaded by `<router-view />`:

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()

console.log(route.name) // -> route.name is defined
```

Note that to access the current route, you should use **useRoute** rather than useRouter (see [Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api#Accessing-the-Router-and-current-Route-inside-setup)).